# Can't get new artifacts on Temple Run 2

Tags: temple-run-2

I can only get the same 5 artifacts on Temple Run 2, and only when I "Unlock the Chest" (from which I only get 1). I can get as many chests as I want during the run, but they never have any. Is there a different way to get artifacts that I just don't know about?

One of my challenges is to get 10 new artifacts but this is making that impossible.

Answer (score -2):

You can probably buy the quest off using the coins